# What is the preferred way to use deep learning to learn output distributions instead of point estimates?

Tags: neural-networks, inference, latent-variable, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I was wondering what would be the preferred model to use deep learning to learn an output distribution instead of a point estimate.

Specifically, there might be the case that certain types of datapoint have associated output quantities (labels or regressed vectors) that are more uncertain (read: noisy) than other types of datapoint. It would be interesting to model that uncertainty so that for a new datapoint a distribution (specified by gaussian parameters mu and sigma) is produced instead of a fixed output quantity (point estimate).

A probabilistic interpretation for a regular neural network is that the error is modeled via a gaussian that is centered in the output vector and has fixed sigma (homoscedastic), and this would lead to our typical RMSE / L2norm loss function.

Would replacing the fixed sigma with a variable quantity that is output from the neural network viable?
This would be similar to the output of the encoder of a Variational Auto Encoder (just before the sampling/reparameterization trick stage).

Has this been extensively explored in literature? Does it ease the learning and lead to better accuracies?

I would be grateful if you can provide some pointers to literature. I found something such as: [Training Neural Networks with
Implicit Variance](http://bayerj.github.io/static/publications/bayer-iconip2013.pdf) and [Mixture Density Networks](http://eprints.aston.ac.uk/373/1/NCRG_94_004.pdf). I wonder if there is more.